# When should I use componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-component

In React `componentDidMount` is used during the mounting phase, for example, one can `setState` and wrap it in `componentDidMount`. But, one can use `setState` directly and then `render` the component.

In which cases should I prefer `componentDidMount` for a mounting phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's useful for several things:

- Starting ajax
- As [the documentation says](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), doing subscriptions to things (for instance, if the component receives updates in some way that isn't handled by its parent component, such as a stream of events from a web socket)

Basically any time you want to kick off a process when the component is first mounted.

The classic example is a component that loads something via ajax. It goes like this:

- In the component's constructor, you create its default state saying it's loading something.
- In `componentDidMount`, you start the ajax call that loads the thing.
- When (if) the ajax call succeeds, you use the data from the call to update state
- You write the `render` method so that it knows about the loading state and shows either loading or the thing that it loaded (or a loading error) appropriately.

(There are situations where you don't want to do that, where you want to load the thing in the parent component instead and only create the component that shows it when you have the thing. But other times doing it directly in the component isn't uncommon, and it makes a useful example.)

Comment: As far as I see, `render` yields static states, whereas, `componentDidMount` express browser events in state.

Comment: @paulocleon - One of the rules of React is that you can't update state in `render` and it must return the same thing for the same props and state. `componentDidMount` is one of the lifecycle methods where you can modify state if you want. `componentDidMount` isn't *just* for browser events (you could use it to subscribe to any information channel in your app that isn't for some reason modelled in React), but certainly hooking into browser events, doing ajax, etc. are a big use case. (Which I think mostly agrees with your assessment above.) Happy coding! :-)

Answer (score 0):

componentDidMount - When you want to execute the functionality only once when component is created.It will be executed only once by react.

Comment: Could you please develop your point through an example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-gjwh9u , Here is example,
We are sending the updated name to the Home component but it is not reacting over the updated data.

Comment: FYI, you can put your examples for things like this **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). It's best to keep the content of your answer (or question) *in* your answer (or question), since off-site resources can be deleted, links can rot, etc.